# Prevent svcutil from generating "EmitDefaultValue=false" attributes

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, svcutil.exe

I've recently been trying to generate data contracts from xsd files, using svcutil like this:

```
svcutil.exe /t:code /dconly /out:MyContract.cs /n:*,My.Namespace MyDataDefinition.xsd
```

The XSD mostly consists of definitions like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="SomeComplexObjectType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FirstData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="SecondData" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

svcutil generates something like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="SomeComplexObjectType")]
public partial class PersonInfo : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{
    private string FirstDataField;
    private string SecondDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string FirstData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FirstDataField= value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string SecondData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.SecondDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SecondDataField= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Which works fine, however, the "EmitDefaultValue=false" attributes are not necessary.  Not to mention that it introduces a lot of noise into the wsdl, adding stuff like this:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="FirstData" nillable="true" type="xsd:string">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

Currently I'm just hand-editing the generated contract, but that is not ideal from a maintenance standpoint.

Does anyone know how to prevent svcutil from automatically generating these EmitDefaultValue=false attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx).

> On schema import, the EmitDefaultValue property is automatically set
>   to false whenever the WCF-specific annotation mentioned previously is
>   detected. It is also set to false for reference types that have the
>   nillable property set to false to support specific interoperability
>   scenarios that commonly occur when consuming ASP.NET Web services

It appears your only choice is to modify the incoming schema so the relevant elements are nillable.

Answer (score 1):

Remember SvcUtil is just a tool.  If it doesn't meet your requirements, write your own tool!

You could use PowerShell to call SvcUtil and edit the generated file whith your custom changes.

A quick example:

```
#Call SvcUtil
& svcutil #Whatever options you want go here

#Read the generated code
$thierCode = Get-Content "generatedFile.cs"

#Copy each line, editing as you go:
$myCode = @("//This file was generated using MySvcUtil.ps1")
foreach($line in $thierCode)
{
    $myCode += $line.Replace("EmitDefaultValue=false", "")
}

#Write the edited code back into the .cs file.
$myCode | Set-Content "generatedFile.cs"
```